# Como implementar 2 Join en una sentencia SQL usando pyodbc?

Tags: python, pyodbc

Este es mi  código

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd

connection = pyodbc.connect(
    "Driver={Driver do Microsoft dBase (*.dbf)};DBQ=c:/simple", autocommit=True
)

sql = "select * from facgen as fa INNER JOIN client as cl ON fa.num__clien = cl.num_client LEFT JOIN pagos as pa ON fa.num__factu = pa.num_factur"

df = pd.read_sql(sql, connection)

print(df)
```

si quito uno de los "join" no marca ningun error pero al agregarle otro, sale el siguiente error

> pandas.io.sql.DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql 'select * from facgen as fa INNER JOIN client as cl ON fa.num__clien = cl.num_client LEFT JOIN pagos as pa ON fa.num__factu = pa.num_factur': ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][Controlador ODBC dBase] Error de sintaxis (falta operador) en la expresión de consulta 'fa.num__clien = cl.num_client LEFT JOIN pagos as pa ON fa.num__factu = pa.num_factur'. (-3100) (SQLExecDirectW)")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error es que estas usando sentencias mysql, entonces al usar pyodbc ya la sintaxis es la de sql server

Si usas el siguiente código debería funcionar

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd

connection = pyodbc.connect(
    "Driver={Driver do Microsoft dBase (*.dbf)};DBQ=c:/simple", autocommit=True
)

sql = "select * from ((facgen as fa INNER JOIN client as cl ON fa.num__clien = cl.num_client) LEFT JOIN pagos as pa ON fa.num__factu = pa.num_factur)"

df = pd.read_sql(sql, connection)

print(df)
```

Como puedes observar se hace una agrupación con paréntesis en los "Join"